# Simulate TAB key pressed in SWT

Tags: java, events, swt, listener

I am trying to simulate a tab key pressed event in SWT, but I cannot find any method to do this.

I have a composite which contains one texfield, one ListViewer and one button.

When I press tab in the textfield I want to set the focus on the button, not on the ListViewer.

Comment: You want to change the tab order. For this use `setTabList(Control[])`

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated this guy?

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet241.java

I haven't tried this sort of thing, but the snippet above changes tab order.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can deal with this:

1. Define a so-called "tab order", which tells the parent to traverse its children in the given order.
2. Listen to `SWT.Traverse`, prevent the event and manually force focus on the button.

Here is some code for both solutions:

1.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Button");
    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER).setText("This won't get focused.");

    shell.setTabList(new Control[] {text, button});

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

2.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Button");
    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER).setText("This won't get focused.");

    text.addListener(SWT.Traverse, e -> {
        if(e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT)
        {
            e.doit = false;
            button.forceFocus();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```